# GREP (or similar function) to determine frequency within and between string in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
s <- c("car, car, car, toy, toy", "toy", "horse, horse", "car, horse")
```

And if I `grep("car", s)` I will be able to get `[1] 1 4`

and if I want to get the frequency, I can do `length(grep("car", s))`

However, I wonder if it is possible to get a result that would also return the frequency of the pattern within and between elemnts?

e.g. expected result would be something like the following:

```
[1] 1 1 1 4
```

and/or

```
$`car, car, car, toy, toy`
[1] 3

$toy
[1] 0

$`horse, hores`
[1] 0

$`car, horse`
[1] 1
```

and/or

```
$`car, car, car, toy, toy`
[1] 3

$`car, horse`
[1] 1
```

and/or

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 1
```

Your answer is appreciated. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stringr` package does this with `str_count`.

```
stringr::str_count(s, "car")
# [1] 3 0 0 1
```